# Pronunciation of 'during' in NA English

Tags: pronunciation

I am just wondering which pronunciation of the two below native speakers of North American English would prefer to use for the word *during*.

> 1. /ˈdəːrɪŋ/
> 2. /ˈd(j)ʊriŋ /

Most of the EFL dictionaries published in Japan list No. 1 as the recommended pronunciation for the word.  Do you have any comment about this information?  Do you think this reflects the facts about the English spoken in North America?

Your feedback is very much appreciated.

Comment: Which professionally compiled English dictionaries have you consulted and why did the information found therein not suffice for your question?

Comment: That depends. There are some speakers in North America who ***never*** use the combination /ʊr/. Those speakers would pronounce it as (1). Most of the rest of us would pronounce it as (2). See the [POOR-PURE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_/r/#Cure%E2%80%93force_merger) split.

Comment: Whether by reality or by consensus, the 'schwa' sound /ə/ is _never_ used in a stressed syllable and is never lengthened with /:/. Did you intend the first syllable to rhyme with 'duh'? I (an AmE speaker) pronounce the first syllable as the [NURSE vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects) namely /ɚ/.

Comment: @Mitch No, the NURSE vowel is /ɝ/, because it’s stressed. /ɚ/ is the unstressed one. A word like *firmer* or *burner* has both versions: /ˈfɝmɚ/, /ˈbɝnɚ/. Sometimes people write those as /ˈfʌrmər/, /ˈbʌrnər/.

Comment: @tchrist I took my IPA from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects It gives for GenAmE  /ɚ/.

Comment: @Mitch: that [ɚ] is never stressed is a convention followed by English dictionaries, and not actually part of IPA. The relevant IPA convention is that two vowels that are identical (even if there is a difference in stress) are represented by the same symbol. One might expect dictionaries for EFL to use actual IPA conventions, and not the English-speaking IPA conventions.

Answer (score 3):

The pronunciations /ˈdəːrɪŋ/ and /ˈdʊriŋ/ are both used by lots of Americans. If you use either one of these, nobody is going to think you're speaking strangely. In some parts of the country, the vowel combination /ʊr/ is slowly disappearing from English and being variously replaced by /əːr/, /ɔːr/, and /uːər/, depending on the exact word and the part of the country you live in.

And if you pronounce *during* /ˈdjʊriŋ/, which I don't believe is very common anymore in American English, nobody is going to notice that, either ... at worst, we'll think you learned English from a British teacher.

Comment: Perhaps it’s because for me the tense–lax distinction is neutralized before phonemic /r/, but I can't for the life of me imagine how /ur/ and /ʊr/ would ever differ, whether in *during* or elsewhere. I guess I do know Easterners how pronounce *tour* with the vowel of *took*, but I use the one from *moon* myself. I always have to listen carefully to make sure they haven’t just said *tore*. :)

Comment: @tchrist: the distinction between /ur/ and /ʊr/ is neutralized for me, too, (except maybe for compound words like *Dudley Do-Right*), although the vowel I use is closer to *took*.

Comment: And lots of Easterners (and I think Southerners, Westerners and Midwesterners as well) pronounce *tour* and *tore* as homophones.

Comment: [OED says Brit. /tʊə/, /tɔː/,  U.S. /tʊ(ə)r/.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/203923)

Answer (score 1):

#### Nursing the CURE Vowel

The pronunciation of ‘during’ with the NURSE vowel /ɜr/ rather than the CURE vowel /ʊr/ is an example of a [current trend in rhotic American accents](http://englishspeechservices.com/blog/the-demise-of-%CA%8A%C9%99-as-in-cure/) of a merger — called, appropiately enough, the [NURSE-CURE merger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_%2Fr%2F) — affecting some words in the CURE group, especially among younger speakers.

Dictionaries have generally been slow to acknowledge this change. While Merriam-Webster lists the pronunciation of [*during*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/during) as:

> /ˈdu̇r-iŋ also ˈdyu̇r-/ = ('dʊr-iŋ, djʊr-)

the entry for [*cure*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cure) itself offers the NURSE pronunciation as an alternate:

> /ˈkyu̇r , ˈkyər/ = ('kjʊr,  'kjɜr)

For both these examples I have supplied a more standard IPA transcription to the right. Your dictionaries in Japan, then, seem to be ahead of the curve in recording this pronunciation. This also suggests that CURE may soon lose its usefulness as a member of a [lexical set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_set).

Now I would suggest that the cause of this merger is the result of the slight lip rounding of an American r reducing the fuller rounding of the /ʊ/, yielding a vowel actually closer to a /ɯ/. That vowel, however, is only found as one possibility in the [New Zealand treacLE set](https://www.victoria.ac.nz/lals/research/projects/grinze-archived/publications/NZE_PhonologyPW.pdf), so American ears are more likely to hear a schwa or an /ɜ/, if they prefer not having a schwa in an accented syllable. But if there is the slightest lip rounding the vowel cannot be /ə/ or /ɜ/.

The difference between the two pronunciations is subtle and not likely noticed by native speakers, especially because a preposition rarely receives sentence stress.

#### D or DJ

Merriam-Webster offers a /dy/ = /dj/ alternative pronunciation. Now that little j is a tricky creature. It can primarily affect the vowel, as in *few* /fju/ or a consonant, as it can here with initial d. This effect is called [palatization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatalization_(phonetics)), where the blade of the tongue moves toward the palate. A long /i:/, for instance, palatizes the k in *key*, but the initial consonant in *cat* is a garden variety k. British speakers may also palatize the t in *tea*.

Americans who regularly pronounce the word as /'dʊr-iŋ/ may palatize the d in certain environments. My own pronunciation is as follows:

> During the day         *No palatization*
>   They fought during lunch.   *Slight palatization*
>   He called during lunch.     *Stronger palatization*

#### Real Life Examples

[Forvo.com](https://forvo.com/word/during/#en) offers registered users the opportunity to record themselves pronouncing words or phrases. Of the North Americans who posted, I heard the following pronunciations:

> /'dɜr-iŋ/  SeanMauch, Tong, migueld, Atalina
>   /'dʊr-iŋ/  mmdills
>   /djʊr-iŋ/  Slick, itiwat, IAmMaidOfTheMist

Since ears have accents as well, others may hear these pronunciations differently.

Compared to the British users, the palatization among the last three North American users is slight. For comparison, the RP pronunciation not only prescribes a palatalized d, but also a schwa glide after the vowel: [/ˈdjʊərɪŋ/](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/during). Of the three British users, TopQuark and BritishEnglish have both palatalized d and glide, while mstorm has the d but no glide.

A special case is at the bottom of the page where an American with a broadcast accent pronounces the sentence:

> He played golf every day during his holiday.

as if he were narrating, say, a war documentary. While his pronunciation would also be transcribed as /djʊr-iŋ/, the vowel rather than the consonant is affected, making the word almost sound like *dearing*.

Comment: In the U.S., it's not just that CURE merges with NURSE.  The CURE vowel splits, with some of the words going to the NURSE vowel and others going to the FORCE vowel. It's very rare that *tour* is pronounced with the NURSE vowel (I have heard it occasionally), which would make *toured* and *turd* homonyms.  Usually, *tour* goes to FORCE, which makes *toured* and my pronunciation of *toward* homonyms.

Comment: Let me remark that I've noticed this pronunciation of *tour* mainly because I wince whenever I hear somebody say something like *"I turd the city"*.  It doesn't happen very often at all.

Comment: I am only going by the article I linked to, which primarily deals with British changes to the CURE vowel. I can't get to _turd_ or _toward_ without putting on one of several heavy Inland South accents.

Comment: I think I actually do have some lip rounding in words with the NURSE vowel--at least, my lips aren't spread as far horizontally when I pronounce it as they are for the FLEECE, TRAP, or DRESS vowels. The consonant /r/, which shows up when an vowel-initial affix is attached to a word ending in the FLEECE vowel, is usually labialized (although this seems somewhat variable for me, and I think with /r/ I tend to use a labiodental secondary articulation rather than a bilabial articulation as with /w/).

Comment: @sumelic: as I mentioned, the r has slight lip rounding, but if you rounded your lips for the entire articululation, you'd end up with something like an œ, I think.

Comment: @KarlG: the Wikipedia article you linked to also discusses the [CURE-FORCE merger.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_%2Fr%2F#Cure%E2%80%93force_merger)  A quote: 'For many American English speakers historical /uːr/ merges with either /ɝ/ when it follows palatal consonants in words like "cure", "sure", "pure" and "mature" or /ɔːr/ in other environments such as words like "poor" and "moor".'

Comment: I know that @PeterShor thinks that *tour* "usually" rhymes with *oar* but I question that. Both *tour* and *doer*  have much the same vowel in the Inland North: that of *two*.

Comment: @tchrist: So that's where that pronunciation is from. I've heard it, but I'm pretty sure I've heard it less often than *tore*.

Answer (score 0):

The dictionaries are correct. While the second pronunciation wouldn't sound *incorrect*, *per se*, it would sound extremely affected—like someone trying to put on a British accent but not quite succeeding.

Comment: I think that really depends on where you live, and what regional dialect of American you speak. Not all of us rhyme *during* and *touring* with *purring*.

Comment: Where in North America would the second pronunciation be seen as correct? Maybe in a high-class New England accent, but those are seen as affected too.

Comment: So do you rhyme *touring* with *boring* or with *purring*? It's ***supposed*** to rhyme with *during*, and neither one of those. I'm talking about the vowel, not the pronunciation *dyuring*, which really does sound affected.

Comment: With *boring*. And "supposed to" in which accent? A General American accent?

Comment: "Supposed to" according to the dictionary. [During](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/during) and [touring](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/touring).  There are lots of Americans who still rhyme *during* with *touring* (although there are also lots who don't), so when you say it sounds "extremely affected", you're probably denigrating over half the population.

Comment: @PinkAmpersand "The dictionaries are correct" Exactly which ones are you referring to? Do those have IPA/pronunciation that you can give (and reference)?